# How to replace Python2 MimeWriter.MimeWriter in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

We are replacing an old Server with a new one, The default installed Python is Python3.
We are trying to update the Python2 code to Python3. I've reach something that doesn't seem to exist in Python3. The Python2 code looks like this:

```
import MimeWriter, cStringIO

#...
out = cStringIO.StringIO()
writer = MimeWriter.MimeWriter(out)
#...
```

Now, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EventsMailer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MimeWriter, cStringIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MimeWriter'
```

There is very little information about this change. All I found is:

1. Python 2.7: "MimeWriter now raises a DeprecationWarning upon import."
2. Python 3.6: "The MimeWriter module and mimify module have been
   deprecated; use the email package instead."

But the "email" module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) of Python3 doesn't even mention "MimeWriter"; no hint/instructions as to how I'm meant to replace this code.